# Automatically adjust width of chip component (div) based on text of child elements

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

I have a parent `div` with `two child divs` (a `span` and a `svg`) implemented from the `Material UI` component library. My goal is that the chip width will adjust based on the length of the text inside (with a sensible minimum width). I always want the same amount of left and right padding within the chip.

When I do not set a width on the parent div (or with widths of 100% or auto), it fills up the entire width of its own parent container, which is wider than I want the chip to go. If I set a fixed pixel width, text that is too long either overflows or is hidden. How can I make this parent div intelligently adjust so it is only as wide as the text (plus necessary padding) and no wider?

(Code below is in React with styled-components, but is semantically very similar to HTML/CSS and operates the same in terms of styling and box model)

```
const Chip = (props) => (
  <StyledChip
    label="I'm a chip! I'm a chip!"
    clickable={false}
    onDelete={() => console.log("I did something")}
    onClick={() => console.log("I did something")}
  />
)

const StyledChip = styled(MaterialChip)`
  // width: 124px  // doesn't work because it doesn't adjust based on child elements
  // display: inline-block // doesn't work because the child elements get distorted
  // display: inline-flex // child elements no longer distorted, but still takes up full width of container despite no width property
  background-color: ${colors.primary200};
  color: ${colors.primary800};
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Work Sans";
  padding-left: 14px; // this and the next row define the consistent padding I want on the chip
  padding-right: 4px;

  & .MuiChip-deleteIcon {
    color: ${colors.primary800};
    margin-left: 8px;
  }

  & .MuiChip-label {
    padding: 0px;
  }

  &:-moz-focusring {
    outline: none;
    background-color: ${colors.primary200};
    color: inherit;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding some aspect of what you are trying to achieve, because the default `Chip` styling adjusts to the width of the content.

Here is an example based somewhat on your styling, but with a few adjustments:

- I hard-coded some colors since I don't know what is in your `colors` object.
- I moved some of the styling to the label (padding, font size)
- I increased the specificity for the styling of the outer div (`&.MuiChip-root`) to ensure it wins over the default styling

```
import React from "react";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledChip = styled(Chip)`
  &.MuiChip-root {
    background-color: lightblue;
    color: darkblue;
  }
  & .MuiChip-deleteIcon {
    color: darkblue;
    margin-left: 8px;
  }

  & .MuiChip-label {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-family: "Work Sans";
    padding-left: 14px;
    padding-right: 4px;
  }
`;

const MyChip = props => (
  <StyledChip
    {...props}
    clickable={false}
    onDelete={() => console.log("I did something")}
    onClick={() => console.log("I did something")}
  />
);

export default function Chips() {
  return (
    <div>
      <MyChip label="Hello" />
      <MyChip label="I'm longer than hello" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Styled Chip]

If this doesn't address your problem fully, please provide a version of this sandbox that demonstrates your problem and describe what should look different.